# ASP MVC Identity - change default database in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, model-view-controller

how can I change the default database for individual user accounts. I use postgresql and I want the ready-made registration and login functions to use my postgresql database, not the default database. I tried to change public ApplicationDbContext ()
: base ("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) with my string, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the "default" connection string at runtime.
What you could do is to provide multiple connection strings , 1 per user and then open new db connections when needed.

So I would assume you would have in your "default" db, a table which would contain a connection string per user.

When needed, you will open the connection to the other db for that user.